VBA: If statement comparing cell addresses?
Writing a macro for data output and I need to compare cell addresses to ensure the macro is pulling data from the correct block of data.
Code Example:

Dim SectionSTART As Variant
    SectionSTART = Range("E14").Address

Dim SectionEND As Variant
    SectionEND = Range("E20").Address

Dim SEARCH As Variant
    SEARCH = Range("E30").Address

If SectionSTART <= SEARCH <= SectionEND Then
    MsgBox ("Data Within Search Parameters")
Else
    MsgBox ("NOT FOUND")
End If


I expected msgbox to return "NOT FOUND".
However, regardless of what cell I select for SEARCH, msgbox always says "Data Within Search Parameters". Even if I put "E1000" - it still says that the address is in between "E14" & "E30".
I'm having a hard time finding information on using if-statement comparators on cell addresses and if it is even possible.

This is not valid VBA syntax - If SectionSTART <= SEARCH <= SectionEND Then you need a separate comparison for each - but even then, I am not sure you can use "greater than" and "less than" with Strings.

Oh. Dang thats right - addresses are saved as strings. I completely forgot about that.
Any suggestions on how to use an if statement to only pull data from a particular section?
I have a couple ideas to work around this. But I'm a beginner so any advice/functions that I might not be aware of would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Side note: there shouldn't be any parentheses after MsgBox

You can use Intersect here:
Dim searchRange As range, rng As range

Set searchRange =Range("E14:E20")
Set rng  = Range("E30")

if Not Application.Intersect(rng, searchRange) Is Nothing then
    MsgBox "Data Within Search Parameters"
else
    MsgBox "NOT FOUND"
end if

